# No puedo definir "client" signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Estoy empezando a trabajar con signalR pero se me presenta un error (he visto varias respuesta por la web pero ninguna me ha ayudado), tengo los siguientes archivos

**genteHUB.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace EjemploSignal
{
    public class GenteHub:Hub
    {
        [HubMethodName("noti")]
        public static void llenarDatos()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GenteHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateDatos();
        }
    }
}
```

**archivo JS**

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.genteHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        cargarDatos();
    });

    $.notificationHub.client.updateDatos = function () {
        cargarDatos();
    };

    function cargarDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "~/Home/lista",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta2) {
                console.log("Respuesta", respuesta2);

            }
        });
    }
```

**referencia de Layout.html**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/enlace.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Tengo 2 errores que me salen el primero es la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun varios ejemplos es porque no pongo el nombre de la clase y otros es que debo poner el nombre del `[HubMethodName]`(ya puse ambos y da igual)

El segundo error me da en el Network:

```
if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }
```

Que es segun porque no se esta generando el archivo `hub`ya sea porque:

- No se esta colocando el orden correcto de los archivos(Cuando segun los tengo en orden "jquery,jquery signal, hub")
- Se debe colocar o no el simbolo (~)(Lo malo es que ya se lo puse y se lo quite y aun persiste el error)

En que me estoy equivocando??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes quitar `$.` de la variable

```
notificationHub.client.updateDatos = function () {
        cargarDatos();
    };
```

Comment: El error desaparece en en consola pero cuando hago un cambio en la base de datos no lanza nada nuevo en consola

Comment: cargarDatos(); funciona ??.... public static void llenarDatos() reliza efectivamente las llamadas ?

Comment: estoy haciendo el ejercicio de este ejemplo http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3319/crud-using-signalrmvc-and-entity-framework-code-first-step-by-step 

realmente no se si funciona o no, pero cuando carga la pagina por primera vez, si entra a cargarDatos me muestra `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EjemploSignal.Models.gente]` (lo que quiere decir que si me llama algo pero en el update no hace nada